# Git - Permamently exclude file (deletion) from commit to master

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on a project with two branches: `master` and `develop`.

In the master branch, there's a `.github/workflows` folder for GitHub Actions.
I don't want that folder in `develop`.

Unfortunately, a colleague once merged `master` into `develop` (for whatever reason), resulting in `develop` containing the workflows folder. Now, there are so many changes to `develop` that resetting to before the merge is not an option.

I have removed the folder from `develop` by executing `git rm .github`.

How do I proceed to merge `develop` into `master` without losing the github folder in `master`?

Comment: [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) ?

Comment: @Luuk Is there a way if the removed folder was already commited to `develop`?

Comment: Sorry, despite the fact that i know about [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), I do not know enough about git to answer a question about the removed folder.

Comment: I wouldn't feel too stupid about not thinking of gitignore; it won't solve this problem.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger You're right. I ended up merging `develop` to master anyway, then commiting the `.github` folder afterwards directly into `master`. Not very delicate, but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to do what you want.

The real issue here is that git is not designed to have different subsets of content on different branches, and in spite of ostensibly being git experts, the folks at github have decided to work against the grain of that fact[1] by storing what is logically repo-wide metadata in a file in the commits.

They don't make it any too obvious in their docs, but a little poking around the support forums confirms that the real workflows integration treats the default branch (usually `master`) as "special" in this regard and just ignores any versions of the `workflows` file other than the one on the current commit of that branch.  (They do mention that you can get to other versions of the file - which presumably would allow you to manually kick them off, etc. - by navigating branches or pr's in the web interface.)

So if it were me, I wouldn't worry about the file being present in other branches; as you're already seeing, it's going to cause more trouble than it's worth, with periodic "leaks" onto other branches and, if you try to clean those up, risk of the one copy that matters being deleted (even if only temporarily).

---

[1] - If that characterization seems unsympathetic to what they're trying to accomplish... well, I guess I am.  It's true that a "good" integration with the git repo would be a bit more complicated; but they could provide tooling to insulate the user from that pretty easily.

Comment: Agreed. I also don't understand why GitHub put actual workflow configuration data into the same structure as project data.